# WooCommerce Cart data send to laravel application

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, woocommerce

Please ask if you dont understand anything.

I am new to wordpress and woocommerce. I have created a laravel application in which payment process is being handled. but the products are in wordpress site. what i want here is that when a user click on proceed to checkout after adding all its items into the cart. it will redirected to laravel application where its payment will be handled. now i have used this hook to set custom url for checkout.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'checkout_url');

function checkout_url($url) {
     global $woocommerce;
     if(is_cart()){
          $checkout_url = 'myURL';
     }
     else { 
        $checkout_url = 'myURL';
     }
     return  $checkout_url; 
}
```

How can i send cart data on this url when the customer click on proceed to checkout?

Comment: if i am not mistaken woocommerce will send the data to checkout url by itself, else there should be another wp/wc hook that builds the checkout data

Comment: but i am not be able to get it.. i have created a post method in laravel. still i didn't get the cart data...